# Why eclipse can not find the hidden .project file until I press Ctrl-H on folder?

Tags: eclipse, hidden-files

I am using eclipse on Ubuntu 11.10

When I try to open an project in eclipse IDE, it complains that the .project file can not be found. Now if I open the project folder in Ubuntu file browser and press Ctrl-H the hidden .project file is shown. After this, moving back to eclipse I can easily open the project.

I need to do this every time I login to ubuntu.

Comment: Plz specify what JDK and Eclipse version are you using.

Comment: Similar Q&A at Stack Overflow? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541907/why-does-eclipse-break-when-the-project-file-is-hidden

Answer (score 2):

This may happen because of a bug in JDK. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541907/why-does-eclipse-break-when-the-project-file-is-hidden) for Windows on StackOverflow but same may be true for Linux/Ubuntu as well. Try updating your JDK to the latest version and then test opening a project with hidden .project file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not ideal, but a quick fix would be to always show hidden files/folders. In Nautilus, in the menu go *Edit>Preferences*, then under the *Views* tab, under *Default View* enable *Show Hidden and Backup Files*. My reason for suggesting this is that you seem more interested in quickly accessing your *.project* file in Eclipse than care about whether hidden files show up in the file manager. Hopefully in the future Eclipse will be able to "see" hidden files automatically.